# Работа административной панели Django

Tags: python, django-admin, redis

У меня есть модель запроса для ChatGPT. Которая не сохраняется в реляционную базу данных и не имеет миграций. А только в redis и оттуда же берутся данные для изменения. Redis прекрасно работает и отображает что промпт в нем создается. Однако я никак не могу понять как работают административные формы django. Почему этот же созданный в редисе промпт никак не хочет отображаться в чате. Возможно ошибка в самом коде или настрйках. Подскажите пожалуйста.Ниже приведу административную форму которую я попытался настроить

```
    @admin.register(Prompt)
class PromptAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Prompt

    list_display = ('author', 'position', 'audience_age', 'audience_gender', 'popular_topics', 'suggested_topics')
    search_fields = ('author', 'position')
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        redis_conn = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
        prompt_json = redis_conn.get('Prompt:1')

        if prompt_json:
            prompt_data = json.loads(prompt_json)
            prompt = Prompt(
                author=prompt_data['author'],
                position=prompt_data['position'],
                audience_age=prompt_data['audience_age'],
                audience_gender=prompt_data['audience_gender'],
                audience_positions=prompt_data['audience_positions'],
                popular_topics=prompt_data['popular_topics'],
                suggested_topics=prompt_data['suggested_topics']
            )
            queryset = queryset | Prompt.objects.filter(id=prompt.id)

        return queryset



# Регистрация моделей в административной панели
ADMIN_SITE.register(GPTProcessingRequest)
ADMIN_SITE.register(Prompt, PromptAdmin)
```